# Remove Document Type Declaration DTD from soap server response

Tags: php, soap, soapui

1. The response my webservice gives is not accepted by my (future) customer's system.
   1.1 Client receives "DTD encountered in SOAP context" error.
   1.1.1 [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_6.0.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/messages03.html)

> 0x00030004
>   DTD encountered in SOAP context
>   Explanation:
>   An XML Firewall service has rejected a SOAP message because the message contained a DTD (Document Type Declaration). Such messages are not allowed by the SOAP standard.
>    Correct the problem by removing the DTD from the XML document or by reconfiguring the XML Firewall service to a non-soap parsing mode, such as "xml" or "unprocessed"-last option not possible because client side-.
>   Administrator response:
>   None
>   Severity:
>   error

2. So, I need to remove the DTD from the xml document.
   2.1 Problem is, we use a soap library that handle this for us. [PhpSoapServer][2]
3. SOAPUI get the response just fine

xml

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.uv.com/wsdl/VoucherService/xsd">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:GetLinkVoucherResponse>
         <url>https://u-v.io/OLaGsFr</url>
      </ns1:GetLinkVoucherResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and raw

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.11.8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers,     Authorization, X-Requested-With
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 15:48:36 GMT
Set-Cookie:      laravel_session=XXREMOVEDCHARg1NzVNSlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVHlJdVwvNUVDMm9uTEtkRjJRSWpRaFwvYjY5NlVuQW5LeHUwMThRbEZoYWY4TkTWFmOVJoalZ3RVNnZUtKRzYzSGxkN2N5UjgzXC9yZ09ST0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImZmNTQyMzIzZWQ1NTE3ZTk2ODM3ZWMwMGIzYmMyMDViNGQ0YThlOWNlNjY0MjJjODM0NWY4NmI0OTI3YjFhOTQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Thu, 16-  Mar-2017 17:48:36 GMT; Max-Age=7200;
path=/; HttpOnly
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Encoding: gzip

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-    ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:ns1="http://www.uv.com/wsdl/VoucherService/xsd"><SOAP-ENV:Body>       <ns1:GetLinkVoucherResponse><url>https://u-v.io/OLaGsFr</url>       </ns1:GetLinkVoucherResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So, how to comply with our (future) customer IBM soap firewall ?

Which part of the raw file is about the DTD ?

context: trying to build a startup after winning sponsored hackathon. I'm the less than tech-savy pm trying to help the tech guys.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can't see `DTD` any where in the question or an xml with such reference.

Comment: Solved ! 

1) Client was calling wrong endpoint  
2) Our server response : 404  
3) IBM firewall interpreted the 404 response as a bad formated SOAP response  
4) Us to client : "Please point to the correct endpoint"  
5) Success